# How to get ess-describe-object-at-point to delete-window when I am done?

Tags: ess

I am reading [this function](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/blob/master/lisp/ess-help.el#L747) and still don't see why it doesn't delete both the buffer and window. Currently it open a new window, and when I hit `C-g` another buffer (even duplicated to the one I am editing) appears in that window, created unwanted layout. See attach screenshot.

[image]

What I want is to get the window behavior like `*Help` buffer when one calls `M-x describe-key` for example: It opens its own window, move focus there, and closes it when I hit `q` or `C-g`.

Answer (score 1):

For now I change `(kill-buffer buf)` in the following section to `(delete-window-on buf)`:

From:

```
(when (and (commandp command)
                   (bufferp buf)
                   (or (not (symbolp command)) ;; kill on lambdas
                       (not (string-match "window" (symbol-name command)))))
          (kill-buffer buf)) ;; bury does not work here :( (Emacs bug?)
```

To this:

```
(when (and (commandp command)
                   (bufferp buf)
                   (or (not (symbolp command)) ;; kill on lambdas
                       (not (string-match "window" (symbol-name command)))))
          (delete-window-on buf)) ;; bury does not work here :( (Emacs bug?)
```

Still feel the window created by `describe-object-at-point` is too intrusive. It should be like `"*Help*"` window. But I don't have time to dig more into this right now.